# VBA - How to access folders on Mac Excel?

Tags: excel, vba, macos

I need a script for Excel-Version of Office 2016 for Mac to make a new folder and open.

The code, I have pasted here does sometimes work and sometimes not.

```
Dim filename As String, lineText As String
Dim myrng As Range, i, j
Dim my_own_filename As String
Dim my_own_path As String
Dim filepath As String

my_own_filename = Dropdown_Variables.Range("J12").Value
my_own_path = Dropdown_Variables.Range("J13").Value

filepath = ThisWorkbook.Path

    If Len(Dir(filepath & "/" & my_own_path, vbDirectory)) = 0 And my_own_path <> "" Then


MkDir filepath & "/" & my_own_path

End If
filepath = filepath & "/" & my_own_path & "/"

If my_own_filename <> "" Then
myfilename = Format(Now, "yymmdd-hhmmss") & "_" & my_own_filename & ".gpx"
Else
myfilename = Format(Now, "yymmdd-hhmmss") & my_own_filename & ".gpx"
End If


filename = filepath & myfilename

Open filename For Output As #1

mx = GPX.Cells(Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Rows.Row
Set myrng = GPX.Range("A1:A" & mx)

For i = 1 To myrng.Rows.count
    For j = 1 To myrng.Columns.count
        lineText = IIf(j = 1, "", lineText & ",") & myrng.Cells(i, j)
    Next j
    Print #1, lineText
Next i

Close #1


    If my_own_path <> "" Then
    Call Shell(filepath, vbNormalFocus)
    Else
    filepath = ThisWorkbook.Path
    Call Shell(filepath, vbNormalFocus)
    End If
End Sub
```

Opening a folder I try...

```
Call Shell(filepath, vbNormalFocus)
```

But this leads to an error, the file is not there. But I only want to open the path..and I know the path for sure.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the solution...

**PART01 - Check if folder exists**

First you need the following function

```
 Function FileOrFolderExistsOnMac(FileOrFolderstr As String) As Boolean
'Ron de Bruin : 1-Feb-2019
'Function to test whether a file or folder exist on a Mac in office 2011 and up
'Uses AppleScript to avoid the problem with long names in Office 2011,
'limit is max 32 characters including the extension in 2011.
    Dim ScriptToCheckFileFolder As String
    Dim TestStr As String

If Val(Application.Version) < 15 Then
    ScriptToCheckFileFolder = "tell application " & Chr(34) & "System Events" & Chr(34) & _
     "to return exists disk item (" & Chr(34) & FileOrFolderstr & Chr(34) & " as string)"
    FileOrFolderExistsOnMac = MacScript(ScriptToCheckFileFolder)
Else
    On Error Resume Next
    TestStr = Dir(FileOrFolderstr & "*", vbDirectory)
    On Error GoTo 0
    If Not TestStr = vbNullString Then FileOrFolderExistsOnMac = True
End If
End Function
```

Now the macro...

```
Sub TestFolder()
Dim my_own_path As String
my_own_path = "Test_Folder"
my_own_path = ThisWorkbook.Path & "/" & my_own_path
    If FileOrFolderExistsOnMac(my_own_path) = True Then
        MsgBox "Folder exists!"
    Else
        MsgBox "Folder does not exist!"
    End If
End Sub
```

**PART 02 - Make a folder**

First the function....

```
Function MakeFolderIfNotExist(Folderstring As String)
' Ron de Bruin, 2-March-2019
' http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac010.htm
    Dim ScriptToMakeFolder As String
    Dim TestStr As String
    Dim FolderStr As String

    If Val(Application.Version) < 15 Then
        ScriptToMakeFolder = "tell application " & Chr(34) & _
                             "Finder" & Chr(34) & Chr(13)
        ScriptToMakeFolder = ScriptToMakeFolder & _
                "do shell script ""mkdir -p "" & quoted form of posix path of (" & _
                        Chr(34) & Folderstring & Chr(34) & ")" & Chr(13)
        ScriptToMakeFolder = ScriptToMakeFolder & "end tell"
        On Error Resume Next
        MacScript (ScriptToMakeFolder)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Else
        FolderStr = MacScript("return POSIX path of (" & _
                        Chr(34) & Folderstring & Chr(34) & ")")
        On Error Resume Next
        TestStr = Dir(FolderStr & "*", vbDirectory)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If TestStr = vbNullString Then
            MkDir FolderStr
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Now the macro...

```
Sub MakeFolderTest2()
'Add folder in the same path as your workbook with this code
    MakeFolderIfNotExist (ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "TestFolder2")
End Sub
```

Credits go to Ron de Bruin
https://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/section3.htm